# Find and confirm unconfirmed users in Cognito using a bash script

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-cli

I am trying to write a bash script to confirm all unconfirmed users in a Cognito User Pool. The documentation [here says](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/cognito/latest/developerguide/how-to-manage-user-accounts.html) that I can use *cognito:user_status* to filter by state. So I wrote this code.

```
#!/bin/bash

USER_POOL_ID=pool_id

RUN=1
until [ $RUN -eq 0 ] ; do
echo "Listing users"
# Here is the problem after the --filter param. How should I query for the unconfirmed users?
USERS=`aws --profile jaws-lap cognito-idp list-users  --user-pool-id ${USER_POOL_ID} --filter 'cognito:user_status="unconfirmed"' | grep Username | awk -F: '{print $2}' | sed -e 's/\"//g' | sed -e 's/,//g'`
if [ ! "x$USERS" = "x" ] ; then
    for user in $USERS; do
        echo "Confirming user $user"
        aws --profile jaws-lap cognito-idp admin-delete-user --user-pool-id ${USER_POOL_ID} --username ${user}
        echo "Result code: $?"
        echo "Done"
    done
else
    echo "Done, no more users"
    RUN=0
fi
done
```

The thing is that the --filter is not configured properly. How should I write the statement so I get the unconfirmed users?

Thanks.

Comment: According to the filter docs, there should be spaces `cognito:user_status = "unconfirmed"`? Any the filter is "not configured properly"? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: I tried it as the documentation says, just like this `--filter cognito:user_status="unconfirmed"`.

Then get this error. 

An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the ListUsers operation: Error while parsing filter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This command worked for me:

```
aws cognito-idp list-users --user-pool-id xxx --filter 'cognito:user_status="CONFIRMED"'
```

Answer (score 0):

for filtering out users wrt confirmation status use cognito:user_status in u r  fitler params

const params = {
UserPoolId: userPoolId,
Filter: `cognito:user_status="FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD"`,
PaginationToken: paginationToken
};

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).